# Visual Studio 2010 launching .NET 2.0 Development Server for .NET 3.5 ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have an ASP.NET / C# solution in VS2010. The Target Framework property for each project is set to .NET Framework 3.5, however:

When I debug the ASP.NET site, using the built in ASP.NET Development Server, the properties pane of the server show we're running in ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.4955.

Are there any other Project / Solution settings I should be updating?

Thanks for any help.

Chris.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.NET Framework 3.5` is in fact an extension to `.NET 2.0`, so this is probably correct.

What I mean is that the `.NET 3.0` and `.NET 3.5` classes are merely extensions to `.NET 2.0`, so the main classes are all still version `2.0`.

Go here to see what I mean: `%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework`

The `v3.0` and `v3.5` directories don't contain much, just the new stuff (eg `v3.0` just contains `WPF, WCF, WWF` stuff).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Quite obvious in the end then. Not sure why I expected to see the server show 3.5.